# Getting wrong result while trying to replace values in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate", 
    COMMISSION_PCT AS "Premium",
    REPLACE('COMMISSION_PCT', '-', '0') 
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

I have to replace empty values in column `COMISSION_PCT` with 0, but I get a new column named 'REPLACE('COMMISSION_PCT','-','0')'

With new solution i get this
[image]

But it doesnt replace empty values with 0

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Human Recources DB

Comment: Please provide an example of the data without the replace, or post the schema for this table. It is helpful to know what the _data-type_ of the `COMMISSION_PCT` column is. Also what database provider are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### update: `COMMISSION_PCT` is numeric

When you want to replace a `null` value with a *default* we can use `COALESCE` or other provider specific implementations like `ISNULL`, `COALESCE` is more compliant across different vendors:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate", 
    COALESCE(COMMISSION_PCT, 0) AS "Premium"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

> **[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)**
> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL. For example, SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value'); returns the third value because the third value is the first value that isn't null.
>
> - This implementation is the same across most of the major database providers, *no I do not consider EXCEL a major database provider.*

We don't use [`REPLACE`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_replace.asp) because it is designed to replace all instances of a *string* within a *string* with the specified value, so to replace all the `-` characters with `0`, but it requires a non-empty string value to operate on, in your case the value is probably missing altogether.

In MS SQL Server you can use `ISNULL` which operates the same way as `COALESCE` but only allows 2 arguments, which is all we need for this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate", 
    ISNULL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0) AS "Premium"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

However *PostgreSQL* does not support `ISNULL` at all, so you must use `COALESCE`. In *MariaDB and MySQL the [ISNULL](https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-isnull-ifnull/)* function returns a Boolean response, `1` or `0`, indicating if the column contains a *null* value. The MySQL equivalent of `ISNULL`, is `IFNULL`. So this is a non-coalesce version in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate", 
    IFNULL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0) AS "Premium"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

Very subtle, and in public domain forums that are trying to be provider agnostic you will see the use of `COALESCE` more often than `ISNULL` because it is less ambiguous and more likely to work when you copy the script.

### Update: OP is using ORACLE

Oracle doesn't support `ISNULL` either, so `COALESCE` is still an option, but there is also a `NVL' function we can use for this same behaviour. [Read more about Oracle ISNULL() Equivalent](https://database.guide/oracle-isnull-equivalent/).

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate", 
    NVL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0) AS "Premium"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

---

In my original post it was not clear if the `COMISSION_PCT` field was a numeric or a string based type. I had assumed a string based column given that OP tried to use `REPLACE` and so I posted the following solution using a `CASE` statement to provide options for *null* or *empty string* values:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate", 
    CASE COMMISSION_PCT 
        WHEN NULL THEN '0'
        WHEN '' THEN '0'
        ELSE COMMISSION_PCT
    END AS "Premium"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```

*Remove the quotes around the `0` if `COMMISSION_PCT` is a numeric type*

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Comment: see my comment in the post: `Remove the quotes around the 0 for numeric types` But I will update the example

Answer (score 0):

If your empty values are kind of "null" you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME) AS "Fn and Ln", 
    HIRE_DATE AS "HireDate",
    ISNULL(COMMISSION_PCT,'0') AS "Premium"
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
```